# Clause type after "to"

Tags: clauses

What is the type of the following bold clause, please?

The woman said nothing but only gestured Jim **to follow her**.

Comment: _gestured Jim_ doesn't work for me.  I would expect _gestured to Jim_.

Comment: The woman said nothing but only gestured to Jim to follow her. That will give you two to's which is right here.

Answer (score 1):

It's an [***infinitive complement.***](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/infinitive-complements.93488/)

In some contexts, such as *He asked me **to go***, the "infinitive marker" ***to*** is required. But in others, such as *He watched me **go***, it's just a "bare infinitive".

Comment: Is the purpose of this clause expressing the reason/purpose?

Comment: I guess, yes. Note that if your highlighted "adverb of purpose" *wasn't* present, it would be perfectly valid to have ***gesture*** as an "intransitive" verb - but that would require the preposition ***to*** between the verb and the object (Jim). Not many native speakers would accept prepositionless *She gestured Jim*, but you should note that many if not most of us would probably include that preposition even in your example (unlike some learners, native Anglophones aren't bothered by multiple instances of ***to*** in close proximity, especially if they have wildly different syntactic roles).

Comment: ....note that I said ***not many*** native speakers would accept prepositionless *She gestured Jim*. Some would, though. Come to that, I've no doubt at least *some* native speakers would accept *She **waved** Jim*. But they would be very rare indeed.

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much for the explanation.

Comment: ...it's less common to associate an "adverb of purpose" clause with ***to wave*** than with ***to gesture***, but [here are some written examples](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22waved+him+to+come+over%22) of *She **waved** [for] him **to come over*** (where preposition ***for*** would often / usually be included).